# Error: Cannot set headers after they are sent while mapping through array of objects and making async db calls

Tags: node.js, rest, mongoose

I have a function in the controller for a post request which receives request body as an array of objects that look like this:

```
[
    {
        "names": ["test company 1","test company 2"],
        "role": "electronics"
    },
     {
        "names": ["test company 3", "test company 4"],
        "role": "mechanical"
    }
]
```

In the controller function I am trying to loop through it and updating many documents and their role like this:

```
exports.setCompanyRoles= (req, res) => {
  req.body.map((data) => {
    Companies.updateMany({ name: { $in: data.names } }, { role: data.role })
      .then((result) => {
        res.status(200).json(result); //I know map is triggering this to be sent multiple times throwing error
      })
      .catch((err) => console.error(err));
  });
};
```

The code then rightly complains of http header being sent multiple times:

```
Listening on port 3002
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:535:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (C:\teamSIO\server\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:771:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (C:\teamSIO\server\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:170:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (C:\teamSIO\server\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:267:15)
    at C:\teamSIO\server\controllers\adminConfigFlow.js:43:25
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5) {
  code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT'
```

I have been trying to figure out whats the best way to do this. Due to async calls I am unable initialize a result variable outside and then update it inside the map function and then use that to send a response.
However, despite this error, the database is able to update correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you already know you can't send multiple responses to the same request.  So, instead, you need to gather all the results and then send one response.  Since you have multiple asynchronous operations that are using promises, you can use `Promise.all()` to know when they are all done and then send an array of results.

```
exports.setCompanyRoles= (req, res) => {
  Promise.all(req.body.map((data) => {
    return Companies.updateMany({ name: { $in: data.names } }, { role: data.role });
  })).then(results => {
       res.status(200).json(results);
  }).catch(err => {
       console.error(err);
       res.sendStatus(500);
  });
};
```

Note, I added a `return` in front of your database call so that your `req.body.map()` will produce an array of promises.  You can then use `Promise.all()` to both know when all those promises are done and to get access to all their resolved values.

FYI, I also added sending an error response in addition to just logging the error since you need to always send a response the http request, even when there's an error.

Comment: Thank you so much! It didnt occur to me to use promises here.